# Why is GoogleAuth failing to refresh in my webapp?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am testing using PyDrive in my web app and the refresh part causes it to return a 500 error. Sometimes it works after awhile but I'm not sure what the conditions are. The same code works locally always. Any idea what could be the issue?

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
gauth.Refresh()
```

Comment: please edit your question include [example] and the full erorr message you are getting not just the code.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Although I can't directly view the errors, it appears trying to refresh authentication tokens on a foreign machine is forbidden. An alternative solution was to go into google cloud and **create a service account key** for my webapp. I downloaded the key as a **json and use that file for authentication**.
[image]
[image]

Additionally, it seems **the service account has its own google drive account that isn't easy to access** with my browser (but I could see/control it using pydrive in a terminal). For convenience, I s**hared a folder using my personal gdrive account to the service accounts email**. So now I have the service account save files to that shared folder and it is easy for me to see and control the contents using my personal account

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
gauth = GoogleAuth()

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secrets_serviceacct.json', scope)

gauth.Authorize()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'testing.txt', 'parents' : [{'id' : 'mygdrivefolderid'}]})
file.Upload()
```